# Category Link go to 404 on store switch

Tags: magento2, category, multistore, store-view, page

I have used **Magento 2** with 2 store view and My default store is English and set Category Link in Mega Menu but when i change my Store view from English to french that category link goes to 404 page.

As the category shows in Menu too.

Answer (score 0):

`Go to Admin > Catalog > Categories > Switch the french store view (in the top left) > Select your category >` then check if the category is enabled.

[image]